# Text Clickable in a paragraph

Tags: iphone

I have a paragaraph where one text should be clickable. How can we achieve this in native iOS app. Dont want to use a webview.

Is it possible to achieve this without webview.

Comment: Have a look at [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

Comment: Is it possible to do without using any library.

Comment: Is your text fixed or dynamic ?